# How do I get this div to be positioned below this search form?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div within a white boarder and a search form within a larger div as you can see from the image below.

[image] 
Problem I'm having is that I want to position the smaller div with the white boarder below the search form but it stays to the left or the right of the search form whatever I do. I've tried several things and nothing is working. Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Note: I'm using wordpress and bootstrap for this.

CSS:

```
#cover {
    padding-top: 110px; /*stops the text from pullung down the image*/
    height: 580px;
    background-image: url('http://image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
#postcode-search {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#postcode-bar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    /*outline: yellow;*/
}
#postcode-btn {
    height: 50px;
}
#postcode-no {
    width: 451px;
    height: 50px;
    display: list-item;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="cover">
        <div class="search-row">

            <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">

              <div class="postcode-search col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <div id="postcode-search" class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" id="postcode-bar" class="form-control" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" placeholder="Enter your postcode"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="postcode-btn" type="button">FIND STORES</button>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
              </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

            <div id="postcode-no"></div>

            <?php
                if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_search' ) ) {
                    echo woocommerce_product_search( array( 'limit' => 40 ) );
                }
            ?>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put the #postcode-no element inside the bootstrap col- element to make sure it stays inside that div. If this doesn't work. Can you inspect your #postcode-no element and make sure it has no position:absolute positioning? Because i also see a bottom: 10px put on that element.

Maybe you can also remove the

```
display: list-item;
width: 451px;
```

and ADD

```
display: block;
```

New HTML:

```
<div id="cover">
    <div class="search-row">

        <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">

          <div class="postcode-search col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <div id="postcode-search" class="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="postcode-bar" class="form-control" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" placeholder="Enter your postcode"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="postcode-btn" type="button">FIND STORES</button>
                </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
            <div id="postcode-no"></div>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

        <?php
            if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_search' ) ) {
                echo woocommerce_product_search( array( 'limit' => 40 ) );
            }
        ?>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

checkout the fiddle
i put `float:left` inside the elements and your postcode-no i put inside a div

https://jsfiddle.net/5cvu8fnq/